# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in... Wordpress 5.3.2 PHP 7.3

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: IMAGEN WORDPRESS]

Ese error me muestra al entrar a un post (Single.php) y al colocar el `<?= get_the_content() ?>`

Desde ya gracias.

Comment: No es un error, es un warning.

Comment: Es un Warning y no detiene el script, si necesitas desactivarlos debes de configurar o tu php.ini o unas líneas en todo tu core que indiquen un ini_set("display_errors", 0)